# How can I create an object of a generic type as a local variable?

Tags: rust

I am writing an N-body simulator using the Barnes-Hut algorithm and implemented SIMD support. I have a `Simulation` struct that takes configurations etc and is used to run the simulation.

The simulation itself uses different backends, e.g. brute force, Barnes-Hut, and Barnes-Hut with SIMD. My idea was to write a trait `Simulator`, implement it for the backends (including a `new` function), and make `Simulation` generic over it. The backends itself store references to the particles, so they have lifetimes.

The simulation creates an object implementing `Simulator` in every time step and then asks for calculations of accelerations. But there, the problem appears:

If I just have the generic `Simulator<'a, ...>`, the created local object tries to have lifetime `'a`, which is always bigger than a local lifetime. Therefore, I tried being generic over `for<'a> Simulator<'a, ...>`, but then, the individual backends can't be used as they are not generic enough. Is this in some way possible to model?

I tried extracting the [essential parts](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c130d5d6c7ee2ff13d5377402084579b).

For now, I can use `Rc`, but with this project, I'm trying to write the code to be as performant as possible, so that seems against my goal.

Comment: "The backends itself store references to the particles" - That's just asking for trouble in Rust. Why do they need to do that?

Comment: Because in order to calculate the force, the backend needs access to the particles' properties, but since I rebuild it every step, I don't want to copy the particles everywhere. Also, the backend uses a tree, which is much worse for cache locality.

Comment: But if the backend is created anew for each step, why does it need to store any particle references anyway? Doesn't it get them as parameters of the relevant function calls?

Comment: I need to calculate the force of each particle on every other one, so I need the references in the backend. Particularly, I use the Barnes-Hut algorithm which stores particles in a tree.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say I completely understand the question, but have you considered using two lifetimes? One associated with the backend, and one with the particle. Something like the following:

```
impl<'a, 'b:'a, T> UsesReferenceLocally<'b, T, TakesReference<'a, T>> {...}
```